# Update textview in activity by button from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to change "text" in the textview from activity to "some text" when the button from fragment is clicked
In the fragment.java I have

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_student, container, false);

       Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text3)).setText("some text");
      });

        return view;
    }
```

but nothing happens when the button is pressed

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/default_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frame1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
```

fragment_student.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="164dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="159dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="319dp"
        android:text="@string/change_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame1, new StudentFragment()).commit();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity:

```
private Textview textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.text3);
        
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame1, new StudentFragment()).commit();

}

public void setTextForTextView(String text) {
    textView.setText(text);
}
```

And in your Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_student, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTextForTextView("some text");
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: bro my code is correct too. I've just had to raise up the memory